# Setup installation Failed

Tags: python, installation

I'm facing a problem during the **uninstallation** of **Python 3.9** [as you can see in the Picture that I Attached with it kidly tell me what is solution of this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acC1b.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily uninstall it from programs and features that  exist in control panel

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your computer does not match with this version python 3.9. Try to download another version of python and set it up again.